# orchard Job Queue - Publish operation with-in a queued job gives exception

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I have a service method `Import()` which creates a new content item and publishes it. If I call this method from my Controller/Action or any Handler, it works fine. But if I try to create job queue for this method, the job is created and the `Import()` method is called, but in fails on `contentManager.Publish(item)` with the following exception, on class `DefaultContentManager.cs`:

```
An exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: could not execute query

[ SELECT this_.Id as Id1_2_, this_.Number as Number1_2_, this_.Published as Published1_2_, this_.Latest as Latest1_2_, this_.Data as Data1_2_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_1_2_, contentite1_.Id as Id0_0_, contentite1_.Data as Data0_0_, contentite1_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_0_0_, contenttyp4_.Id as Id2_1_, contenttyp4_.Name as Name2_1_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp4_ on contentite1_.ContentType_id=contenttyp4_.Id WHERE contentite1_.Id = @p0 and this_.Published = @p1 ]

  Name:cp0 - Value:1  Name:cp1 - Value:True

[SQL: SELECT this_.Id as Id1_2_, this_.Number as Number1_2_, this_.Published as Published1_2_, this_.Latest as Latest1_2_, this_.Data as Data1_2_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_1_2_, contentite1_.Id as Id0_0_, contentite1_.Data as Data0_0_, contentite1_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_0_0_, contenttyp4_.Id as Id2_1_, contenttyp4_.Name as Name2_1_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp4_ on contentite1_.ContentType_id=contenttyp4_.Id WHERE contentite1_.Id = @p0 and this_.Published = @p1]
```

My `Import()` method looks like this:

```
public void Import(string id)
{
       ...
     var item = contentManager.New("MyType");
         contentManager.Create(item, VersionOptions.Draft);
       ...
        contentManager.Publish(item);
}
```

This exception occurs on the following statement:

```
return contentItemVersionCriteria.List<ContentItemVersionRecord>()
```

Comment: Could you actually post the whole classes. seems the proof is in the pudding...